# Directive declaration

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives

I have a project on Angular. I learn that I need to declare every module that has a lot of features on a higher level on my app and it will be available on all my components and sub-modules. But I have a special case with a directive. I made a simple directive and import it on my `app.module.ts`.

I made this diagram for a better understanding:

[image]

I want to use this directive on a component that is part of another module (this module is declared on my `app.module.ts` too). So I put my directive on this component and it doesn't work. But if I move the import to this sub-module then works.

What things can I declare on a higher level module and which things should I not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Angular module provides for template resolution. Any nested component, directive, or pipe used by a template associated with a component declared in an Angular module must also be either declared or imported into that Angular module.

You can share components, directives, and pipes using a shared module.

See this video for more information on template resolution and shared modules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o&t=4s

Comment: your presentation is so amazing! I would have wanted to be there! My confussion are about the inheritance with the modules. I was thinking that if i have a service declared on the top module it will be avaliable on the entired app. This is true according your presentation. I should not declare a service on differents modules. And the directives? Applies on the same way of the services, right? The concept of have a shared module is great. Thanks a lot for taking of your time for this. 
I appreciate it too much.

Comment: Thank you so much! Services declared at the module level are available to all components in the application. Directives are declared or imported into one specific module and are only available to the components declared within that module. Hope this helps!